# firebase 3/AngularFire 2 cannot catch error when trying to set firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Firebase v3.2.1
AngularFire 2.0.1

I try to set firebase, I got this error:

```
Error: Firebase.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'products.xxx.longDescFR'
```

but I cannot catch the error, no console log displayed!

```
firebase.database().ref('products').set(productList).then(function(ref) {
      console.log(ref)
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Failed: ' + error);
    });
```

any idea how to catch the reject/fail promise?

Chuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `catch()` clause is called when the write fails on the server, so when the security rules reject the operation.

When you're passing in `undefined`, the operation already fails on the client. You could probably `try catch` it, but it's way better to simply detect the `undefined` and not write:

```
if (productList) {
    firebase.database().ref('products').set(productList).then(function(ref) {
      console.log(ref)
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Failed: ' + error);
    });
}
```

Comment: oh yeah working! My productList in not undefined, but corrupted (Excel=>CVS=÷some line were missing some fields). I put it in a try catch  and I was able to catch the error! Thanks!